Efficient way to clean 8752 pictures from the very similar one
I have 8752 pictures that was converted from, more or less, an hour long CCTV video with Python script screenshotting. My supervisor told me to clean the data from the roughly similar one. At first I was thinking to make a program that:

Convert each pictures to Numpy Array
Substract picture a1 to picture a2 then compare it's similarity percentage
Continue to whole 8752 dataset.

I need opinion in these method since this is my first time taking data from outside (not from prepared dataset) and going to use it in my machine learning model. Is my method truly inefficient as my supervisor said?
Also, did my "screenshotting program" could take each frame correctly without missing any data from the video?
This is my code to take pictures of the video:
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture("siang.mp4")
net, image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
while net:
    cv2.imwrite("frame" + str(count)+ ".jpg" , image)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print("Read a new frame: ", success)
    count +=1
    if (count==5139): #estimated seconds from the video length
        break;

The image is in .jpeg format and has 1420 x 1080 size after cropping.
Would be happy to provide more details if needed.

We can't really say something about this... we don't have enough context to provide something meaningful and we can't really read the mind of your supervisor. Maybe ask him.

@LucasMorin I have provided contexts needed such as images specification and the number of it, I thought the community has their ways to clean their data of duplicates that's why I thought the question make sense. well supervisor told me to check it one by one I'm sure it's not the most efficient method out there isn't it?
